# Using varargs to create an object in a class

Tags: java, class, constructor, arguments, variadic-functions

I am trying to create a class called GameCharacter which represents a game character and has the
following properties:
• name (a String)
• powers (a set of Power objects)

How do I set up an object like this, within a class? The constructor must use varargs as Powers can have different parameters. This is my attempt, but clearly is does not work!
This is from a past 2019 assignment question that I don't have solutions for, and I'm a beginner at java. Any help understanding this is appreciated!

```
    class GameCharacter{
    private String name;
    private int cost;
    class Powers{
        public Powers(Power... powers) {
            for (int i: powers) {
                this.i = powers
                
            }
        }
    }
    
    //constructor
    public GameCharacter(String name, int cost, Power... powers) {
        this.name = name;
    
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## For a set of `Power` objects, use `Set < Power >`

If you want to track a set of `Power` objects, use the [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html) class. No need for varargs, just pass a `Set` object.

To make this very simple, let's use the `Record` feature coming to Java 16. The compiler implicitly creates the constructor, getters, `equals` & `hashCode`, and `toString`. A record is appropriate when the main purpose of the class is to transparently and immutably carry data. Using records makes this example code much shorter.

```java
package work.basil.example.Game;

import java.util.Set;

public record GameCharacter (String name, Set <Power> powers)
{
}
```

For an unmodifiable `Set`, use the [`Set.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#of(E,E)) methods.

```java
package work.basil.example.Game;

public record Power(String description)
{
}
```

```java
package work.basil.example.Game;

import java.util.Set;

public class App
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        App app = new App();
        app.demo();
    }

    private void demo ( )
    {
        GameCharacter susan = new GameCharacter(
                "Susan" ,
                Set.of(
                        new Power( "invisibility" ) ,
                        new Power( "force field" )
                )
        );
        GameCharacter ben = new GameCharacter(
                "Ben" ,
                Set.of(
                        new Power( "physical strength" ) ,
                        new Power( "rock-like hide" )
                )
        );

        System.out.println( "susan = " + susan );
        System.out.println( "ben = " + ben );
    }
}
```

When run:

```
susan = GameCharacter[name=Susan, powers=[Power[description=force field], Power[description=invisibility]]]
ben = GameCharacter[name=Ben, powers=[Power[description=rock-like hide], Power[description=physical strength]]]
```

If you were to define conventional classes rather than `record`, you would define two member fields on your `GameCharacter` class: `String` for name, and `Set < Power > powers` for the collection of `Power` objects. And you would add a constructor taking two arguments for those two fields.

```java
package work.basil.example.Game;

import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Set;

public final class GameCharacter
{
    // Member fields
    private final String name;
    private final Set < Power > powers;

    // Constructor
    public GameCharacter ( String name , Set < Power > powers )
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.powers = powers;
    }

    public String name ( ) { return name; }

    public Set < Power > powers ( ) { return powers; }

    @Override
    public boolean equals ( Object obj )
    {
        if ( obj == this ) return true;
        if ( obj == null || obj.getClass() != this.getClass() ) return false;
        var that = ( GameCharacter ) obj;
        return Objects.equals( this.name , that.name ) &&
                Objects.equals( this.powers , that.powers );
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode ( )
    {
        return Objects.hash( name , powers );
    }

    @Override
    public String toString ( )
    {
        return "GameCharacter[" +
                "name=" + name + ", " +
                "powers=" + powers + ']';
    }
}
```

## Varargs

Now we can get back to your specific Question: how to handle varargs in your constructor.

Here we add a second constructor to the class seen above. This second one takes a varargs of type `Power`.

The varargs arrives as an array of `Power` objects. We can loop the elements of that array with the for-each syntax. We add each element to a new `Set` implementation of our choice, in this case the [`HashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashSet.html) class.

```java
    public GameCharacter ( String name , Power... powers )
    {
        this.name = name;
        Set<Power> s = new HashSet <>();    // New empty `Set` implementation.
        for ( Power power : powers )        // `powers` is the varargs array of `Power` objects.
        {
            s.add(power);                   // Add each element of array, each `Power` object, to our `Set` collection.
        }
        this.powers = s;
    }
```

To use this constructor, we tweak our `App` class to drop the calls to `Set.of`.

```java
package work.basil.example.Game;

import java.util.Set;

public class App
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        App app = new App();
        app.demo();
    }

    private void demo ( )
    {
        GameCharacter susan = new GameCharacter(
                "Susan" ,
                new Power( "invisibility" ) ,
                new Power( "force field" )
        );
        GameCharacter ben = new GameCharacter(
                "Ben" ,
                new Power( "physical strength" ) ,
                new Power( "rock-like hide" )
        );

        System.out.println( "susan = " + susan );
        System.out.println( "ben = " + ben );
    }
}
```

Here is the source code for the entire class of our revised `GameCharacter`, now offering two constructors.

```java
package work.basil.example.Game;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Set;

public final class GameCharacter
{
    // Member fields
    private final String name;
    private final Set < Power > powers;

    // Constructors

    // First constructor
    public GameCharacter ( String name , Set < Power > powers )
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.powers = powers;
    }

    // Second constructor
    public GameCharacter ( String name , Power... powers )
    {
        this.name = name;
        Set<Power> s = new HashSet <>();
        for ( Power power : powers )
        {
            s.add(power);
        }
        this.powers = s;  
    }

    // Getters

    public String name ( ) { return name; }

    public Set < Power > powers ( ) { return powers; }

    // `Object` overrides

    @Override
    public boolean equals ( Object obj )
    {
        if ( obj == this ) return true;
        if ( obj == null || obj.getClass() != this.getClass() ) return false;
        var that = ( GameCharacter ) obj;
        return Objects.equals( this.name , that.name ) &&
                Objects.equals( this.powers , that.powers );
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode ( )
    {
        return Objects.hash( name , powers );
    }

    @Override
    public String toString ( )
    {
        return "GameCharacter[" +
                "name=" + name + ", " +
                "powers=" + powers + ']';
    }
}
```

Tip: If you want your member field `powers` to be an unmodifiable set, you can reduce that second constructor to this:

```java
    // Second constructor
    public GameCharacter ( String name , Power... powers )
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.powers = Set.of( powers ) ;  // Make an unmodifiable set from the varargs array.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a lot of difficulties:

1. Wrong `foreach` declaration.
2. Different types and method parameter names.
3. Missed field with type Power into class Powers.

I guess what you want to do maybe it, but your question needs moderation.

```
class GameCharacter{

    private String name;

    private int cost;

    class Powers{
        
        public Powers(Power... powers) {
            for (Power i: powers) {
                //what initialize do you want?  
            }
        }
    }

    //constructor
    public GameCharacter(String name, int cost, Powers powers) {
        this.name = name;    
    }
    
    class Power{
        
    }
}
```